# AnacondaのパッケージMatplotlibをPython IDLEで使用したい。

Tags: python3, anaconda, matplotlib

Python IDLEでMatplotlibパッケージを使用したいのですが、Anacondaをインストールした後に、IDLEでMatplotlibをインポートしても以下のようなエラーが発生(numpyはインポート成功したのですが）してしまいます。ちなみにTerminalではきちんと機能します。

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 23, in <module>
import matplotlib.text as text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 33, in <module>
from matplotlib.backend_bases import RendererBase
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 66, in <module>
import matplotlib.backend_tools as tools
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 487, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Comment: 作業中のディレクトリに.pycファイルありませんか？あれば一度消してみてください。